# Tomcat access log rotated file delete within minutes

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat7, access-log

I am generating tomcat localhost access logs using the class -

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"  fileDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm" renameOnRotate="true" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" maxDays="<%= @access_log_max_days %>"`

Since my node doesn't have sufficient memory for all access logs, I would like to delete the rotated files after 10 min or so. My question is how can we provide a decimal value (or < 1days) value for `maxDays` construct so that deletion of rotated files occurs more rapidly than once everyday?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the value of `maxDays` is an integer, with values not greater than `0` meaning no rotation. So the minimal value you can set is `1`.

Anyway log files spanning a couple of minutes wouldn't allow you to diagnose **almost any** problem. Logs take a couple of orders of magnitude less space on disk, than any web application you might deploy, so I don't think rotating logs every day will be a problem.

**Edit:** A setting of `maxDays="1"` will still leave you with two log files: the current one and the previous one. If you wish to have just the current one you can disable rotation in Tomcat and use an external utility like [logrotate](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/logrotate.conf.5.html):

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"  
       prefix="localhost_access_log"
       suffix=".txt"
       rotatable="false"
       checkExists="true" />
```

**Logrotate** can rotate based on file size, so it should resolve your problem.